# OCUnit doesn't work with security framework?

Tags: ios, keychain, ocunit

When attempting to add secure entries into the keychain using:

```
SecItemUpdate((CFDictionaryRef)queryKeychain, (CFDictionaryRef)updateAttributes);
```

I'm getting an *errSecNotAvailable* error returned but only when running my unit test target.
Is the keychain not available during unit testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the security framework included in the OCUint target?

I just tested and I have no errors, I can add an item and change an item in the Keychain in an OCUint test.

I may have my OCUnit setup differently, I am testing against the app, not including the apps files into my unit test.

Comment: Yes, I made sure it was linked.